# Ability to add customized views to a standard entity in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am in need of creating a view for an entity that seems to be a standard/system entity.  Is there a way to enable "Customization" to this entity so I can create a new view? At this moment, "Add" option is missing (refer to 2nd screenshot).

Also, when I view "Managed Properties" for this entity, it is greyed out.

NOTE*: I have administrator rights.

[image: Attempt to create a view for the entity]
[image: Entity Lookup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the entity customizable by updating Entity table:

```
update [MSCRM].[MetadataSchema].[Entity] set IsCustomizable = 1, ismanaged = 0 where name like 'RLM_StandardCharge'
```

Answer (score 3):

That entity does not look as a system entity, personally I've never seen it and the name has a prefix "rld" that make me guess that it's part of a managed solution that was imported to that environment.

As you probably know, managed solutions allow to use managed properties to block some features and prevent users from introducing changes (for instance you can lock down the creation of new forms/charts/view in an entity). As you can see in your first screenshot, the entity State column has a value of Managed which means that you will have some restrictions to personalize/extend that entity.

Long story short, I believe that unfortunately you won't be able to create a new view but you can confirm that selecting the entity and clicking "Managed Properties" in the command bar:
[image]